# Dyanamically duplicate the div using textbox value (Number) using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating POC. In one scenario I have to enter the number in the text box based on count of the number div has to generate with id Currently I have created variable call Count I am assigning count for loop the div and the button was generating with ID. But this was not happening when I enter the number in the textbox.

Here is the code

```
function createElements(){
    var count = 5,  

    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        button = document.createElement('button');
        button.className = "btn";
        button.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + j]);
        button.innerHTML=[1 + j];

        div.className = "page";
        div.setAttribute('id', ['page' + j]);

        div.style.position="absolute";            
        fragment.appendChild(div);
        fragment.appendChild(button);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/c0x6mjac/4/)

Kindly Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are duplicating the `ids` of the elements by using so. Keep track of it using a global counter.

```
// Maintain a variable that holds the current value
var totalCount = 0;
function createElements(){
 var count = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page").value;
    // Gaurd condition
    // Only if it is a number
    if(count && !isNaN(count)) {
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            button = document.createElement('button');
            button.className = "btn";
            button.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + totalCount + j]);
            button.innerHTML=[1 + j];

            div.className = "page";
            div.setAttribute('id', ['page' + totalCount + j]);

            div.style.position="absolute";            
            fragment.appendChild(div);
            fragment.appendChild(button);
            totalCount++;
        }
      document.body.appendChild(fragment);
    }
}
```

[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0x6mjac/8/)

**EDIT**

Also avoid binding the events inline. Use Vanilla JS to bind the events as it helps in separation of concerns.

```
   // Maintain a variable that holds the current value
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page"),
    totalCount = 0;
debugger;
inputElement.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    var count = this.value;
    // Gaurd condition
    // Only if it is a number
    if(count && !isNaN(count)) {
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            button = document.createElement('button');
            button.className = "btn";
            button.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + totalCount + j]);
            button.innerHTML=[1 + j];

            div.className = "page";
            div.setAttribute('id', ['page' + totalCount + j]);

            div.style.position="absolute";            
            fragment.appendChild(div);
            fragment.appendChild(button);
            totalCount++;
        }
      document.body.appendChild(fragment);
    }
});
```

**[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0x6mjac/12/)**

Comment: @Mahadevan My bad..  2 things to be noted. The event bound should be `blur` and not `click` ..  And the second option under the Extensions of jsFiddle should be `onLoad` or `in body` as the element should be available when the event is bound. I have edited the fiddle for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not support the `onfocusout` event, you can use `onblur` instead. 
Also you can use `event.target.value` to get the number of elements you want to create. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/c0x6mjac/9/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/c0x6mjac/7/

```
function createElements(){
 var count = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page").value;  

        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            button = document.createElement('button');
            button.className = "btn";
            button.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + j]);
            button.innerHTML=[1 + j];

            div.className = "page";
            div.setAttribute('id', ['page' + j]);

            div.style.position="absolute";            
            fragment.appendChild(div);
            fragment.appendChild(button);
        }
      document.body.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputAdd_page"   onblur="createElements(this.value)" />
    <div id="page" class="page">
        &nbsp
    </div>
```

For your Javascript:

```
function createElements(value){

    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var j = 0; j < value; ++j) {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        button = document.createElement('button');
        button.className = "btn";
        button.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + j]);
        button.innerHTML=[1 + j];

        div.className = "page";
        div.setAttribute('id', ['page' + j]);

        div.style.position="absolute";            
        fragment.appendChild(div);
        fragment.appendChild(button);
    }
  document.body.appendChild(fragment);
}
```